# Adding a column to my Word table fails with run-time error 5941

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

When I run this VBA code in macros, it reports

> "Run-time error '5941': The requested member of the collection does not exist"

on the highlight line

```
Sub addColumn()
'
' addColumn
'
'
Application.Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks
Dim myDoc As Document
Set myDoc = Word.ActiveDocument
Dim myTable As Table
With myDoc
  iCount = myDoc.Tables.Count
  For i = 1 To iCount
    Set myTable = myDoc.Tables(i)
    myTable.Columns.Add BeforeColumn:=myTable.Columns(6)
  Next
End With
End Sub
```

Could anyone give me some advice?

I wrote this code for dealing with a word.doc which contains lots of tables(606 tables) and other characters. I want to use macros to add a column at the end of each table in the batch. Did I miss something?

[image]

Comment: One of your tables has <6 columns?

Comment: Instead of Tables.Columns(6) try Tables.Column.Last

Comment: If a table has horizontally merged cells that will also cause your code to fail.

Comment: @freeflow «Instead of Tables.Columns(6) try Tables.Column.Last» Ans if some tables already have more than 6 columns and the idea is to insert a new one after the 6th?

Comment: @macropod The op specified at the end of the table. When pointing out shortfalls in posts by others its helpful if you also suggest a solution.

Comment: @TmothyRylatt, true so lets add a test for myTable.Uniform being true and flagging an error if its not.  When pointing out shortfalls in posts by others its helpful if you also suggest a solution.

Comment: So what were are really pointing the OP to is the fact that they have made an assumption about the number of columns in the table and the absence of any horizontally merged cells.  SO the op might want to consider adding tests for the number of rows and the uniformity of the table before adding a column after column 6

Comment: @freeflow Well, the OP's code does say to insert the new column *before* column 6... If all the OP wants to do is to append a column after the last column, see my answer.

Comment: So another learning point.  Always read the question and check that the op's code is actually doing what the question is about.  In this case there is a mismatch between the question and the code so let's hope the OP can clarify what they mean.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is to add a new column after the last column in each table, all you need is:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Tbl As Table
For Each Tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
  Tbl.Columns.Add
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```